# Setting custom 404 error in a single subdirectory (apache and .htaccess)

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple wordpress page with some news. In root directory I've set .htaccess with rules:

```
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
```

As you can see it's set that if client requests a file or dir that doesn't exist he's redirected to /news/index.php.

Now, I would like to set that if he calls for non existing graphic file from /news/wp-content/uploads/ subdirectory he should get a custom graphic instead (let's say /news/wp-content/uploads/noimage.png). For this I modified .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /news/wp-content/upload/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME !-f
RewriteRule . /news/wp-content/upload/notFound.png

RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
```

But now when I try to load page (even index page) I get internal server error. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule is actually hijacking all the legit WP requests since those are never for a valid file. Replace your complete code with this:

#### if there is no .htaccess in wp-contnent directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads)/.+$ $1/notFound.png [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

#### if there is .htaccess in wp-contnent directory then use this code on top of `wp-contnent/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^uploads/.+$ /news/wp-content/uploads/notFound.png [L,NC]
```

Comment: Now the page opens up but still I don't get custom image in place of missing onec...

Comment: When I try to open this file manually in the browser I get internal server error (the file does exist on disc in the proper dir)

Comment: That is what I wrote in my answer that `/news/wp-content/upload/notFound.png should exist` You're actually trying to catch 404 with something that also doesn't exist. If you comment rule above `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` then are you able to load `http://domain.com/news/wp-content/upload/notFound.png` in browser?

Comment: I said that the file exists physically in the proper directory. And yes, once I commented the rewriterule I can open the file notFound.png...

Comment: Alright that's very good to know that without additional rule that notFound image is being loaded. Let me test this with my WP setup and update the answer in few minutes.

Comment: I realize 3 issues. 1) Closing `}` missing in my `RewriteCond` above. 2) I mis-spelled `upload` instead of `uploads`. 2) Wordpress also has a .htaccess in wp-content directory. I am fixing 2 & 3 above meanwhile please check and let me whether you have .htaccess in wp-content and/or in uploads directory?

Comment: Version with .htaccess in wp-content did not work (I added especially for those lines) but the one with .htaccess in main directory works fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling with the RewriteBase, why don't you try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/wp-content/upload/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /news/wp-content/upload/notFound.png [L]
```